# How do i make an image cover another image?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my first website and I've stumbled across a problem.
How do i make my main contentBox cover the subNav? [Img Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulFRk.jpg)

Comment: Hi Joakim. Please post the relevant part of your HTML mark-up in the question. Use the `{}` button to format as code. Also consider mocking up your problem in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and linking to that also.

Comment: How are you positioning elements on the page? You could use "style='position:absolute; left=100px; right=100px;'" in the html of the contentBox. 100px is just an example to demonstrate syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `z-index` property.

Answer (score 1):

To get an image over another image:

Using CSS, absolutely position your image and set the top value to 0 for both images.

However, I am not sure you are asking the correct question as in your image, your content areas seem to be above the area you want them to be placed.

Also - are your web page areas all images?

Comment: Yes, they are all images, is that bad?

Comment: It's not bad as such, just probably unnecessary. You could use divs then use CSS to colour them and position them more easily.